# Convert struct to double type in Matlab

Tags: matlab, struct, double, matlab-struct

Glcm (feature extraction method) give me an output in 'struct' type, while i need the output in 'double' type. I need a 'double' type as the input variable for the next step.

[image]

So, I've tried to convert it using several code showed below.

```
[gl] = glcm (B);
[gl] = struct2cell (gl);
[gl] = cell2mat (gl);
[fetrain] = double (gl);
```

The code give me an output but it's in 'complex double' type.

[image]

Is there a better way to convert 'struct' to 'double' type?

Or to convert 'complex double' to 'double' type?

Any help and suggestion would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How about using `struct2array`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, rather than first converting to a cell and then to a matrix, you can convert directly from a `struct` to a `double` using `struct2array`.

```
fetrain = struct2array(gl);
```

That aside, there is no difference between a "complex `double`" and a `double`. They are both of type `double`.

```
class(1i)
% double
```

You can use `real` to get the real component of  the complex number or `abs` if you need the magnitude of it.

```
real(1+1i)
%   1

abs(1+1i)
%   1.4142
```

In your case this would be:

```
fetrain_real = real(fetrain);
fetrain_mag = abs(fetrain);
```

**Update**

By default `struct2array` concatenates the data horizontally. If you want your data to be a matrix that is `nFields x nData`, then you could do something like the following:

```
fetrain = struct2array(gl);

% Reshape to be nFields x nData
fetrain = permute(reshape(fetrain, [], numel(fieldnames(gl)), numel(gl)), [2 1 3]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Suever

Surprisingly, it's so simple.

Comment: But wait @Suever, what happen with the matrix, it gives value =1x3222 double , it supposed to be 22x601 (fields x total data). Look at the picture of variable, that i've shared above.

It must be precise, because I need to use it for training using Artificial Neural Network .



Hope you can help.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you explain more, I get this error 
"Undefined function 'fieldnames' for input arguments of type 'double' "

Then, I try define the fields. With this: fields = fieldnames (fetrain);


>> fetrain = permute(reshape(fetrain, [], numel(fields(gg)), numel(gg)), [2 1 3]);

But get this error : "Subscript indices must either be real positive
integers or logicals."

Thanks before @Suever